# Espressif SDK ESP8266 for OSX

Tags: macos, esp8266

I want to install Espressif SDK and required tools for building and flashing the  ESP8266 firmware on OSX, but I only found it for Debian and Windows

Comment: Install Oracle Virtualbox on your Mac for free and install Debian inside that - assuming that any hardware involved is USB-attached and can be *"passed through"* from OSX to the Debian virtual machine.

Comment: Do you need any more feedback? If not please [close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK itself is completely platform agnostic - It doesn't care what OS you're running. You simply need a toolchain built for your version of OS X. The ESP8266 Open SDK community have put this repo together for instructions on compiling the toolchain and setting up the SDK to work with it:

https://github.com/pfalcon/esp-open-sdk

You should be able to follow the Mac OS instructions on there.

Alternatively, the ESP8266 Arduino project hosts prebuilt toolchains for OS X, Linux, and Windows. They also made a Python script here that sets most of it up for you:

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/get.py

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give you a few pointers (too long for a comment). I'm not 100% you really want to work with the SDK directly or rather with a firmware that *uses* the SDK to build a higher level API on top of it.

If it's the later there are several options to build NodeMCU for example (cloud, Docker): http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/build/

For flashing I suggest you give esptool.py a try: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/flash/#esptool